# filezilla connection failure

Tags: html, ftp, filezilla

I have tried to connect to my websites ftp with filezilla, but this error keeps appearing:

```
    Status: Waiting to retry...
    Status: Resolving address of helloworld.net
    Status: Connecting to 12.345.678.910:11
    Status: Connection attempt failed with "EACCES - Permission denied".
    Error:  Could not connect to server
```

what do I do?

Comment: This doesn't belong here. Try [superuser.com](http://superuser.com/) or [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com/)

Comment: @A.K Just vote for closing the ticket.

Comment: why are filezilla and ftp tags then? get out of my face and stop wasting time. YOU are no help and should not even be in this post. GOOD BYE.

Answer (score 0):

Check your firewall(s) as well as any portforwarding that may be needed.

http://forum.filezilla-project.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=7704&p=72986